# Is the compatibility info in the PSN Store 100% accurate?

Tags: psn, ps-vita

Below are screenshots from BR and EU PSN Store, respectively. Note that "PS Vita" is not present in the left image. Should I trust this info? I wanto to get this game, but this got me worried.

Seems like there's no logic in the same game be compatible with PS Vita into a region, but not in other.

[image]

Comment: It's possible for Vita games to be region-locked, although Sony heavily discourages it.

Comment: As a side note, the US PSN Store also lists the Vita under its Playable On section... which makes me wonder if the Brazil store is out of date and/or missing tags.

Comment: @Powerlord, the strange is the all PSP games I've bought in Brazil's Store are the same version from US region.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just bought the game to test this, and the information is correct. I sadly could not download it to my PS Vita.

Comment: If you have a PS3, you could try downloading this on your PS3 then transfer the game to your Vita.

Comment: You could try contaction Sony about the issue, all PS One sould be playable on all platforms: PSP, PS3 and PS Vita, because they are essentially just data images that run on emulator.

Comment: My guess is it comes down to regional licensing/fees and someone might not have decided to pay the licensing/distribution cost for the region.

Comment: @Nolonar, I've already asked for a refund, if they not agree to do it, I'll try do that.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin, unfortunatelly this doens't work that way. There so many games I'd like to play in PS Vita that aren't avaliable in Brazil's Store. I should had make an US account before getting a lot of games.